# Evaluating an indefinite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I need help evaluating the following indefinite integral explicitly

$$\int \frac{1}{1+t^{2^{-n}}} dt$$

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Changing the integral from definite over $(2,x)$ to indefinite is a significant change. So is asking for exact evaluation instead of the original question which asked for a series. You should instead add a new question. Also, you should update the title.

Comment: Sorry, I made a comment about changing it a while back, I appreciate the time you spent, and your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Using the substitutions $t=u^{2^n}$ and $u=\dfrac{v}{1-v}$ and $\mathrm{d}u=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{(1-v)^2}$ , we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^x\frac1{1+t^{2^{-n}}}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^{x^{2^{-n}}}\frac1{1+u}\,\mathrm{d}u^{2^n}\\
&=2^n\int_0^{x^{2^{-n}}}\frac{u^{2^n-1}}{1+u}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{$\ast$}\\
&=2^n\int_0^{x^{2^{-n}}/(1+x^{2^{-n}})}\frac{v^{2^n-1}}{(1-v)^{2^n}}\,\mathrm{d}v\\
&=2^n\,\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{x^{2^{-n}}}{1+x^{2^{-n}}};2^n,1-2^n\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathrm{B}$ is the [Incomplete Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

---

Starting with $(\ast)$, we can verify Ethan's formula:
$$
\begin{align}
&2^n\int_0^{x^{2^{-n}}}\frac{u^{2^n-1}}{1+u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-2^n\log\left(1+x^{2^{-n}}\right)+2^n\int_0^{x^{2^{-n}}}\frac{1+u^{2^n-1}}{1+u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-2^n\left(\log\left(1+x^{2^{-n}}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}x^{k2^{-n}}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

An upper bound is given by ignoring the $1$ in the denominator: $$\int_2^x \frac 1{1+t^m}dt \lt \int_2^x \frac 1{t^m}dt=\left.\frac 1{1-m}\cdot\frac 1{t^{m-1}}\right|_2^x$$  The only time this will not be accurate is when both $m$ and $x$ are small, so much of the area comes where $t^m$ is not too much larger than $1$.

Added:  the new version is the same as the original question, with $m=2^{-u}$, though this suggests that $0 \lt m \lt 1$

Comment: I appreciate it this, but unfortunately I am working with a sequence of small $m's$, namely $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8}..$. Also it would help alot if I had an exact evaluation possibly in terms of a series.

Comment: I changed the question slightly I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{1+t^{\frac{1}{2^n}}} = \frac{1}{t^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{t^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}} = \frac{1}{t^{\frac{1}{2^n}}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k ( \frac{1}{t^{\frac{1}{2^n}}})^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k  \frac{1}{t^{{\frac{1}{2^n}}(k+1)}}$, and this convergence is uniform for $t \ge 2$.

Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_2^x \frac{1}{1+t^{\frac{1}{2^n}}} dt &=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \int_2^x \frac{1}{t^{{\frac{1}{2^n}}(k+1)}} dt \\
&=&  \sum_{k=0,\, $k \ne 2^n-1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{1-{\frac{1}{2^n}}(k+1)} ( \frac{1}{x^{{\frac{1}{2^n}}(k+1)-1}}  - \frac{1}{2^{{\frac{1}{2^n}}(k+1)-1}} ) + (-1)^{2^n-1} \ln \frac{x}{2}\\
&=& \sum_{k=0,\, $k \ne 2^n-1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{1-{\frac{1}{2^n}}(k+1)} ( \frac{x}{x^{{\frac{1}{2^n}}(k+1)}}  - \frac{2}{2^{{\frac{1}{2^n}}(k+1)}} )  + (-1)^{2^n-1} \ln \frac{x}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: It doesn't look like the resulting series would work out well for rational $m$ note that the denominator $\frac{1}{1-mk}$, has a singularity at $m=\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: You are correct; I missed the rational part...

Comment: I believe it is fixed now, albeit messier.

Answer (score 2):

I evaluated it explicitly, but thanks for the help you guys.

$$\int \frac{1}{1+t^{2^{-n}}}dt=-2^n\ln(x^{2^{-n}}+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^{k2^{-n}}}{k2^{-n}}$$

Comment: I verified your answer. (+1)